# Does WPF have a MouseDown event that fires until the mouse button is released?

Tags: .net, wpf

**Background:**

In WPF, certain events fire repeatedly during an operation. For instance, during a Drag and Drop operation, the DragOver event fires repeatedly.

**Question:**

Is there a WPF event (presumably a Mouse related event) that fires repeatedly while a mouse button is down?

Comment: what do you want that for?

Comment: Just looking to learn if such a thing exists in the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Instead use MouseUp (Attached Event).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup.aspx for reference.

What you could do is set a timer the repeatedly fires events, set to begin on MouseDown, and have the timer stop on MouseUp.

Comment: What does that msdn winforms link have to do with WPF?

Comment: Good question - I'm tired and didn't get the correct link. lol